# An internal error occurred Cannot revert commit because it has 0 parents, only commits with exactly one parent are supported

Tags: git, github

commit 4c5d2e9a3697dda68d86db5ee6ef188669edbc4d

Author: lokanath  2014-03-11 00:51:58

Committer: lokanath  2014-03-11 00:51:58

Branches: master

1 st commit

But when i am doing commit revert i am getting a error like this

"An internal error occurred
Cannot revert commit '4c5d2e9a3697dda68d86db5ee6ef188669edbc4d' because it has 0 parents, only commits with exactly one parent are supported"

ca any one tell me why it is so ?

Answer (score 2):

You only have one (1) commit, the initial (root) commit.

Reverting a commit requires comparing the commit against its earlier, parent commit to see what changed.  This requires an absolute minimum of two (2) commits, so that there are some commits (plural) to examine to see what changed between them.

Thus, you may not revert the one initial commit.  (That's just a git limitation—there's no version-control-system reason one should not be able to make a second commit that undoes the first one so that the checkout would be completely empty—but git itself is not very good with empty directories.  However, even if the git folks fixed this in git so that you *could* revert your initial commit, the result would be a completely empty checkout anyway, which is not very useful.)

(What you *can* do is amend the initial commit, if you want the initial commit to look somewhat different.)

Answer (score 0):

> git update-ref -d HEAD

I had the same problem. The above command solved it for me.